# Navegar e recuperar objetos DOM via getElement sem utilizar WebBrowser

Tags: c#, dom, navegador-de-internet

Existe alguma forma de realizar navegação em páginas da web, criar requisições do tipo `.Document.getElementById(" ")` sem a necessidade de utilizar o componente `WebBrowser()` no meu formulário?

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("http://");
//[...]
var valor = browser.Document.getElementById("");
```

Idealmente realizar as navegações e requisições, sem a necessidade do sistema realizar a *renderização* da página web.

A ideia é fazer com que o carregamento das páginas seja realizado o **mais rápido possível**, para acessar uma quantidade muito grande e sequencial de páginas, recuperando suas informações em elemetos de ID específicas.

Além disso, há alguma forma de esperar o carregamento completo da página ser realizado antes de criar a requisição `getElementById`, sem utilizar *(para o `WebBrowser`)*:

```
while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Se não tem a página carregada como conseguiria obter elementos dela? Pode detalhar mais o cenário? Quando diz "quantidade muito grande e sequencial de páginas" refere-se mais concretamente a quê?

Comment: Olá @JoãoMartins, eu gostaria de carregar a página sim, só gostaria de saber se há mais alguma forma de carregar páginas, acessar seus objetos utilizando uma alternativa para o WebBrowser(), pois o meu sistema irá carregar uma página, recuperar um valor dela, ir para próxima página, recuperar o valor dela... Assim por diante. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode baixar o conteúdo da página utilizando o WebClient ou HttpClient, ler o conteúdo e pegar somente o valor que você deseja. Você pode fazer isso, por exemplo, utilizando o [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). O exemplo abaixo é para pegar o título de uma página, mas também pode ser feito de outras maneiras, talvez mais simples.

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
string tituloGoogle = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["html"].ChildNodes["head"].ChildNodes["title"].InnerHtml;
```

Comment: Excelente, era algo exatamente assim que eu precisava! Muito obrigado pela ajuda Ives, é de grande valia.